# Ghost API - Not Getting Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, ghost

I am using Ghost API to get the content from another website. I am using below mention code and it gives me a 403 Forbidden error.

```
function onSuccess(data) {
   var $result = $('#blog-posts');
   $.each(data.posts, function (i, post) {
     $result.append(
      '<li>' + post.title + '</li>'
     );
   });
}  

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery.get(
  ghost.url.api('posts', {
    limit: '3', 
    include: 'tags', 
    order: 'count.posts DESC'
  })
).done(onSuccess);
});
```

Comment: This can't be anything to do with **Ghostscript**....

Comment: Then how can I get content through Ghost API?

Comment: I don't know, because I know nothing about **Ghost** which is apparently a blogging platform, unlike **Ghostscript** which is a PostScript and PDF interpreter. My comment is to explain why I removed the Ghostscript tag.